# Importing orders, how to applay discount amount

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, import, cart-rule

I have made a script for migration orders from prestashop to magento 1.8.1.0. All orders were imported successfully. I have just one problem. I don't know how to apply discount amount on order and how to show discount amount and description in customer order history list.

I tried to create cart price rule and apply it on quote with this [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programmatically-create-apply-and-delete-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento/) but without success.

```
    ...   
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order_no);                  
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(false);
    $quote->collectTotals();
    $quote->setCouponCode('my_discount_code')
    $quote->save();
    ....
```

I tried to apply discount amount on order object with bellow code:

```
...
$order->setDiscount($total_discount);
...
```

Does anyone have any experiences with importing orders in magento and how to apply discount?

Comment: Be careful with the date the tutorials you're looking at were released. A lot happened in magento between now and then. Btw, you didn't tag your Magento version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is quite simple:

```
$orderObj->setDiscountDescription('description');
$orderObj->setDiscountAmount(-$total_discount);
$orderObj->setBaseDiscountAmount(-$total_discount);
$orderObj->setCouponRuleName('rule');
$orderObj->setCouponCode('code');
```

Comment: Magento normally also distributes the discount amounts across the items. I would suggest taking a look on the database level how the order is saved when placing an order via Magento vs your script.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question as resolved. This platform is still in beta and we need to reach an answer rate of 80%. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/ Thanks!